# PHP Fileinfo extension at php.ini does not exist, PHP 5.4

Tags: php, php-5.4, fileinfo

I searched alot on how to enable php_fileinfo extension, but here in my php.ini file and it doesn't contain any php_fileinfo thing, I'm using PHP 5.4 on a dedicated windows server.

Should I add a extention = php_fileinfo.dll, will it work?

Comment: The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php) maybe able to help.

Comment: Thank you @JonStirling, it says: Windows users must include the bundled php_fileinfo.dll DLL file in php.ini to enable this extension. so does it mean that i should include this line at php.ini?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` solved the problem! for more information read this article: https://community.xibo.org.uk/t/how-do-i-enable-fileinfo-in-php/78